# Is there a non-browser based version of Pandora?

Tags: pandora

Is there a Windows based widget or something I can use to play Pandora without keeping the browser open. Like a system tray icon program or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though a paid app, [Pandora One](http://www.pandora.com/pandora_one) is the official desktop application built with Adobe Air.

Comment: I might want to point out that the audio comparison under the Higher Quality Audio section is a LIE. Free Pandora radio doesn't sound that bad, and the high quality example has some nasty tricks (such as a high-end exciter turned all the way up) that give the illusion that it's much better quality with the paid version. You'll still be able to hear a difference, but not to that extent.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Mac OS X, you might also consider [Musicality](http://industriousone.com/musicality) ($10), which has Pandora and Last.fm support. I've been using it for several months, and it's been great so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something free, OpenPandora works well enough.

http://getopenpandora.appspot.com/